# How do I change window size?

Tags: dayz-2012

Looking in the video settings there appears to be only one interface resolution setting that allows me to play windowed and the screen is tiny, I also can't resize the window.

How do I play in a larger window, or alternatively, tab out of a full screen window without minimising the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Arma2 Startup Parameters](http://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Arma2:_Startup_Parameters#Display_Options) page:

1. Add "-window" to your command line/shortcut
2. In [arma2.cfg](http://community.bistudio.com/wiki/arma2.cfg) add the following lines:

> ```
> Render_W=2400;
> Render_H=1500;
> Resolution_W=1920;
> Resolution_H=1200;
> ```

`Resolution` sets the interface size and `Render` sets the 3D rendering resolution.